# Use another ssl certificate even if server has other certificates

Tags: tls, laravel

I deployed a laravel project to a server (in which I have root access). Then I was asked to install a ssl certificate to that project. But there are some projects that already have installed a ssl certificate in the server.

My question is if I install another ssl certificate (for example: Let's Encrypt's free ssl certificate) only to my new project, does it break other projects' ssl certificates ?

It is first time that I am installing a ssl certificate so I am reading and watching videos, how to install ssl. I am afraid of breaking other working projects.

It will be good if you provide a safe procedure how to install.

> Server's OS: Debian,
>   Webserver: nginx.

I can't communicate with server's administrator!

Comment: That depends entirely on how the server is set up. Why do you say you can't talk to your sysadmin?

Comment: @MechMK1, sysadmin has gone somewhere so I must do everything myself.

Comment: Given that you have root access, you are the sysadmin now. How are projects separated?

Answer (score 1):

First, SSL / TLS is quite an advanced setup. you will need to research how it works and test it on another machine before even attempting to do it on a production machine.

If you have a modern setup, (e.a. you have an [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) aware webserver, and clients.)
you can setup multiple TLs certificates, see the [NGINX documentations regarding virtual hosts and multiple SSL](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

To test with Ceritficates you id not buy, but only use for Testing / Development (ea. NOT PRODUCTION) you can use [mkcert](https://mkcert.dev/) or [xca](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/).

the last thing I would recommand after you tried your setup on the production server, is to use a service like [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to validate your setup. (do it for ALL domains with TLS in your server)

as a footnote to get a good cipher suite list, try [cipherli.st](https://cipherli.st/)